# How to force raid1 mirror to stripe on read

Tags: performance, software-raid, mirror

I use RAID1 - mirror long time. I have beleaved yet, that RAID1 does stripping on read operation for improve the speed.

While migrating form 160GB disk to 3TB mirror, I started the file copy, watching the real speed on mirrored volume as on mirror members. 
I'm disappointed that all the read concerns the `/dev/sdb` only while the other member is sleeping. 
Do somebody know how to force the stripe-read operations on RAID1?

OS Debian Linux 9 Stretch, mdadm, ext3/4

Comment: Depends on virtually _everything_ used in your config. RAID controller, HDDs/SSDs, cache/nocache, drivers, etc. Don't rely on RAID1 to be faster than a single drive, especially not when using single thread file transfers. Ah, using mdadm, I skipped that. Have a look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/385519/does-raid1-increase-performance-with-linux-mdadm or that: https://serverfault.com/questions/814546/how-to-obtain-read-speeds-of-two-disks-using-mdadm-btrfs-raid1-or-zfs-mirror

Comment: I prepare the test with RAID10 on two disk: mirror1 sdd1 & sde1 in strip with mirror2 sde2 & sdd2. Could it confuse the mdadm raid1 procedure. (?)

Comment: Which test are you talking about? Careful, mdadm's RAID10 is not the same as other RAID10s (in your case it should be, though), [look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_RAID_levels#Linux_MD_RAID_10). Also: read performance of RAID10 differs quite much from RAID1.

Comment: Thanks for the wiki link, that's what I want to test (far layout). Two disk, two partitions on each, and first mirror, than strip. First strip, than mirror - it looks more dangerous from my point of view. I will share my results, sure.